# How to open flutter app using another app

Tags: android, flutter

Is there anyone know how I can open flutter app from another android app. What I want to achieve is to open my flutter app from my other android application.

Comment: do you mean this? https://flutter.dev/docs/development/add-to-app/android/project-setup

Comment: No my app is independent and working but I also want to open this app from my another app

Comment: I guess you are talking about deeplinks

Comment: take a look at this: https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking